# Adding or removing a class to an element dynamically using Mutation Observer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I want to remove a class from an element when a modal pops-up But when I searched online I found **DOMNodeInserted** and it was working until it went live and the error I got was **DOMNodeInserted** has been deprecated. 
 *The error I keep getting below*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56a4c.png)

> CODE WORKING BELOW, but has been deprecated.

```
    $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
            if ( $("body").hasClass('modal-open') ) {
                $(".hide-search").hide();  
                // $(".nav-menu").addClass("border-0");
            } else if ($("body").hasClass('modal-open') === false){
                $(".hide-search").show(); 
                // $(".nav-menu").removeClass("border-0");
            }
        });
```

> New code i wanted to Implement but i don't know how to go about it.

```
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
            console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)

            // observe everything except attributes
            observer.observe(body, {
            childList: true, // observe direct children
            subtree: true, // and lower descendants too
            characterDataOldValue: true // pass old data to callback
            });
             });
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

- observe() should be outside the callback
- all you need to observe is the `class` attribute, nothing else, so there's no need for the extremely expensive `subtree:true`.
- the `class` may include something else so you need to ignore irrelevant changes

```
new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
  const oldState = mutations[0].oldValue.split(/\s+/).includes('modal-open');
  const newState = document.body.classList.contains('modal-open');
  if (oldState === newState) return;
  if (newState) {
    $('.hide-search').hide();
  } else {
    $('.hide-search').show();
  }
}).observe(document.body, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['class'],
  attributeOldValue: true,
});
```

Comment: Just checking in, thanks for this. I was able to resolve this with the code below

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the above problem with this solution

```
 function myFunction(x) {
            if (x.matches) {
            var body = $("body");
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
                var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
                console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
                if(attributeValue == "ng-scope modal-open") {
                    $(".input-group").addClass("removeDisplay");  
                    $(".nav-menu").addClass("hide-nav-menu");
                } else {
                    $(".input-group").removeClass("removeDisplay");  
                    $(".nav-menu").removeClass("hide-nav-menu");
                }
                }
            });
            });
            observer.observe(body[0], {
            attributes: true
            });
            }
            } 
            // Wow It's working.
            var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1240px)")
            myFunction(x) 
            x.addListener(myFunction)
```

Firstly I used a match media to check if the screen is lesser than 1240px size then I used the mutation along with checking if an attribute class is present, then perform some certain actions based on that.